# What are the differences between the different UIDs in Knex?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'm using Knex and I want to measure the time it takes for a query to run in the database so that I can raise a warning for slow queries.

I was going to use the listeners Knex provides but when it came to identifying the queries I see there are 4 different UIDs: `__knexUid`, `__knexTxUid` and `__knexQueryUid`.

I cannot find what each one is supposed to identify.